# Text not centered inside the last tab bar (Qt)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qtstylesheets, qtabbar

I have this gfx bug : The text "AUDIO" of the Tab 2 is not centered

text of tab 2 is not centered (screenshot)

[image]

I have this bug only on Mac when I add the log out button like that inside the MainWindow's constructor :

```
m_logoutPushButton->setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton"
    "{"
    "border-color:#77bdd8;"
    "color:#77bdd8;"
    "}"
    ""
    "QPushButton:hover"
    "{"
    "border-color:white;"
    "color:white;"
    "}"
);
m_logoutPushButton->setFixedSize(121, 23); // size used for all buttons
ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->setTabButton(2, QTabBar::RightSide, m_logoutPushButton);
```

The bug only appears when I "add" the log out button like that :

```
ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->setTabButton(2, QTabBar::RightSide, m_logoutPushButton);
```

This is the code of my MainWindow's StyleSheet :

```
QMainWindow
{
background-color:#77bdd8
}

QFrame
{
background-color:#77bdd8;
border-color:#2b80c3;
color:#2b80c3;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
padding: 1px 0px 1px 3px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

QWidget
{
background-color:#77bdd8
}

QLabel
{
color:white;
border-color:transparent;
}



QPushButton
{
background-color:transparent;
border-color:#2b80c3;
color:#2b80c3;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
padding: 1px 0px 1px 3px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

QPushButton:hover
{
background-color:transparent;
border-color:white;
color:#5bb0f3;
 }

QTabWidget::pane {
border: 0;
}

QTabWidget  QTabBar {
  background: url(:/assets/image/logosmall_colored.png);
  background-repeat: norepeat;
  margin-top: 0px; /* whatever needed to center the image vertically */
}
QTabWidget QTabBar::tab:first {
  margin-left: 67px; /* at least the width of your image */
}


QTabWidget QTabBar{
background-color: #136ba2;
width: 256px;
font: 20pt "Oswald";
font-size: 20px;
}

QTabWidget QTabBar::tab{
background-color: #136ba2;
height: 52px;
width: 256px;
color: #e6e6e6;
border-color:transparent;
}

QTabWidget QTabBar::tab:selected{
background-color: #0f5d90;
width: 256px;
}


QTabBar::tab:last {
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    margin-right: 356px;
}


QListWidget
{
color:white;
font: 20pt "Oswald";
font-size: 20px;
}

QListWidget:hover
{
border-color:white;
}

QLineEdit
{
color:white;
border-color:#2b80c3;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
padding: 1px 0px 1px 3px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
font: 18pt "Oswald";
font-size: 18px;
}

QLineEdit:hover
{
color:white;
border-color:white;
}

QPushButton
{
background-color:transparent;
border-color:#2b80c3;
color:#2b80c3;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
padding: 1px 0px 1px 3px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
font: 16pt "Oswald";
font-size: 16px;
}

QPushButton:hover
{
background-color:transparent;
border-color:white;
color:white;
 }

QPlainTextEdit
{
border-color:transparent;
border: 0px;
color: white;
font: 16pt "Oswald";
font-size: 16px;
}

QPlainTextEdit0
{
border-color:transparent;
font: 10pt "Oswald";
font.pointSize:20;
border: 0px;
color: white;
font.family: "Helvetica";
font.pointSize: 24;
}
```